# How can I have a variable and a function with same name in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to have a variable and a function with same name, therefore I have this codes:

```
var testString: String = "some string from variable!"
// use case: print(testString)
```

---

```
func testString() -> String {

    return "some string from function!"

}
// use case: print(testString())
```

As you can see there is a big difference in both use cases! one like `testString` and the other with `testString()`, but xCode complain this to me:

```
Invalid redeclaration of 'testString()'
```

Which I do not know why it has to be an issue! one thing is a variable and other is function!

How ever I done a little hack and I deformed the function to this one in down, now it compile and no issue! the use case is still the same like `testString()`

```
func testString(_ value: String? = nil) -> String {

    return "some string from function!"

}
// use case: print(testString())
```

Now I have the things I wanted, but I have unwished initializer for function! how can I solve this issue in general?

Comment: There is no way to accomplish what you want. If you assign the result of it to another var what would you expect to happen? A new String object or a new func object?

Comment: String for sure, so what u mean?

Comment: `let result = testString` can result in `let result: () -> String` as well

Comment: Yes for sure! I know it! I wanted a closure at first then I realized it and changed it to function.

Comment: I wonder why the compiler doesn't complain about your second case. It should at least complain that it could not infer the resulting type.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I think I could not ask my question well, my issue is there if I am not allowed to use `print(testString())`, then how can I bypass the issue with an initializer which I am not doing explicitly and Swift make it for my as infer.

Comment: I wonder why would you need to use the exact same name for a method and a variable. Just use different names. I mean would you accomplish something greater using the same namespace?

Comment: You are right! I have to use your advice, for me was good to have 'testString' and 'testString()' but it is hard and difficult for xcode. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not possible, as they share the same namespace:

https://forums.swift.org/t/why-doesnt-swift-allow-a-variable-and-a-function-with-the-same-name/5038